# Nextjs css variable not defined

Tags: css, next.js, less, styled-components, css-variables

I have a Next.js project that uses `styled-components`, `variables.less` imported in `global.less` and theme object that is available globally for all components.

theme.ts fonts vars

```
font: {
        weight: { regular: 350 },
        family: {
            bold: 'var(--bold-font)',
            medium: 'var(--medium-font)',
            light: 'var(--light-font)',
            book: 'var(--book-font)',
            roboto: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
        },
    },
```

variables.less

```
@bold-font: 'GothamRounded, Bold', Arial, sans-serif;
@medium-font: 'GothamRounded, Medium', Arial, sans-serif;
@light-font: 'GothamRounded, Light', Arial, sans-serif;
@book-font: 'GothamRounded, Book', Arial, sans-serif;
```

styled component

```
font-family: ${({ theme }) => theme.font.family.book};
```

the problem is that some variables work some dont, and I cannot figure out the pattern to solve the problem. The variable can be undefined randomly, `@white: #fff` works but `@asd: #fff` does not. Am I doing something wrong?